Python finds another file
If I have a folder with two python scripts: contants.py and appl.py (inside the folder something) and the files are
THEKONST = 5

and
from something.constants import THEKONST

print(THEKONST)

What do I have to do so that I can call python something/appl.py and not run in the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'something' 
Note: I cannot modify the scripts or how they call the other
Edit:
Trevor's method worked
mmm,,, funny, the exact same code in last night attempt does not work with this method....so I erased everything and redid everything but not on vscode but with touch and copy paste and now it works.... and I still don't know why... but at least now it is working (I am just writing this as a memo)

Drop the something..

Or, if something/__init__.py exists and your PYTHONPATH includes the current working directory, you can use python -m something.appl

@KlausD. That is the catch. It is code written by someone else. I can not modify the code

Is there a setup.py file or similar in the root? If so, you should be installing the application (ideally into a virtualenv or similar), not trying to run it direct from the source tree. That is to say, python path/to/script.py is usually the Wrong Thing for things that are components of larger applications as opposed to standalone scripts. Right now, though, there really isn't enough information in the question to tell how the author of the project you're deploying intended it to be used.

Moreover, whatever setup.py or equivalent there is will often specify an "entrypoint" for anything intended to be started from the CLI, such that the installation process will itself create an executable wrapper you can call from the command line without putting python on your command line at all.

@CharlesDuffy so the only way is to modify the PYTHONPATH? I will try that tomorrow thanks! (here it is midnight and I am half asleep)

@KansaiRobot, "only way"? No, certainly not the only way, but you aren't giving us enough information to know if it's necessary, so specifying it as a necessary step is the easiest thing to do in absence of more details. The python -m something.appl approach may work without any PYTHONPATH changes at all -- it certainly will work without PYTHONPATH changes if you successfully install the larger project into an a virtualenv that's active when you're trying to run the program.
